# Search HTML tag with regex

Tags: regex

According to http://gskinner.com/RegExr/, it provided a regex pattern to search for HTML tag:

**A)** `<[^<]+?>` - Simplified example of matching HTML tags

It works, however I changed the regex pattern as below, it also work.

**B)** `<[^<]+>` or **C)** `<[^<]+.>`

I want to ask what is the different between **A)**, **B)** and **C)**?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`+?` is what is known as lazy. Lazy matching will match **as few characters as possible.** For example, `<[^<]+?>` given `<blah>>` will match `<blah>` even though it could have matched `<blah>>` because it matches the fewest possible characters it can.

Conversely, `+` is known as greedy and matches the most possible characters it can. It will match `<blah>>` since that is the most it can match that satisfies the regex.

`.` is a character meaning 'match anything', and on its own (no +, *, etc after it) it means 'match one anything'. The `.` in `+.` does not modify the `+`, it is a new element.

As you can see, we use `+?` because an HTML tag closes on the first `>` encountered, and `+?` reflects this by ending as soon as it can close the HTML tag.